# The tilde operator not working in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ng-if

The tilde operator `~` not working in `ng-if` directive but I can check the condition like this `message.indexOf('angular') > 0`.
I want to know why the tilde operator not working inside the HTML.

In the html:

```
<div ng-if="~message.indexOf('angular') ? true : false">...</div>
```

In the angularJS:

```
$scope.message = 'Hello angular';
```

Error appears in the console

```
angular.js:13920 Error: [$parse:lexerr] Lexer Error: Unexpected next character  at columns 0-0 [~] in expression [~message.indexOf('angular') ? true : false].
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/$parse/lexerr?p0=Unexpected%20nextharacter%20&p1=s%200-0%20%5B~%5D&p2=~message.indexOf('angular')%20%3F%20true%20%3A%false
    at https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.8/angular.js:68:12
    at Lexer.throwError (https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.8/angular.js:14179:11)
    at Lexer.lex (https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.8/angular.js:14101:16)
    at AST.ast (https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.8/angular.js:14303:30)
    at ASTCompiler.compile (https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.8/angular.js:14771:31)
    at Parser.parse (https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.8/angular.js:15700:29)
    at $parse (https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.8/angular.js:15865:39)
    at ChildScope.$watch (https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.8/angular.js:17104:19)
    at Object.link (https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.8/angular.js:26396:16)
    at https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.8/angular.js:1247:18
```

Comment: why are you using **~** any specific reason?

Comment: Nothing special. Mostly have used the tilde operator to check condition for `indexOf()` in the JavaScript. So I have tried same in the html but it's shown error. @Aravind

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Angular's template expression syntax is much *like* JavaScript expression syntax, but it's still not JavaScript.

The key differences are listed [in the documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression) and one of them states

> - No Bitwise, Comma, And Void Operators: You cannot use Bitwise, , or void operators in an Angular expression.

[Being a bitwise operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Bitwise_NOT), `~` is not supported.